# Ajax success paramater after PHP function call

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to do an `$.ajax` call to a PHP file (`microsubs.php`), I need to have a success call to if person is in IP range. Below is the PHP code:

```php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$public_ip_ranges = array();

$range = (object) array();
$range->name = '123 Media';
$range->lower = '10.1.0.0';
$range->upper = '10.1.255.255';
$public_ip_ranges[] = $range;

$range = (object) array();
$range->name = '123 media 3';
$range->lower = '141.228.0.0';
$range->upper = '141.228.255.255';
$public_ip_ranges[] = $range;

$range = (object) array();
$range->name = 'vaerrrrrr';
$range->lower = '146.127.0.0';
$range->upper = '146.127.255.255';
$public_ip_ranges[] = $range;

if (($lngIP=ip2long($ip)) < 0) $lngIP += 4294967296;  

foreach ($public_ip_ranges as $ip_range) {
   if (($lngLow=ip2long($ip_range->lower)) < 0) $lngLow += 4294967296;
   if (($lngHigh=ip2long($ip_range->upper)) < 0) $lngHigh += 4294967296;
   if($lngIP >= $lngLow and $lngIP <= $lngHigh) {
        ?>
```

And below is my Ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url: "/microsub.php",
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (){
    }
});
```

What do I put in the `success` callback to see if the person is in the IP range function running in the PHP file?

Comment: You have to echo something out in the PHP to get a return via AJAX. Then do `success: function (response){...` [Whatever PHP echoes will be in `response`.](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Note there are trivial syntax errors in your code, like orphaned curly barckets (`{`) and script tags (`?>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP echo your result: for example `1` if the IP is in range:

```
if($lngIP >= $lngLow and $lngIP <= $lngHigh){
    echo 1;
}else{ echo 0}
exit;
```

In Javascript, read the result and do what you'd like with it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/microsub.php",
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data){
        var inRange = (+data===1);
    }

});
```

Comment: What is this `var inRange = (+data===1);`?